# How to write push_back_first_odd function in python?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, pycharm

Write a code to make a function "push_first_odd_back". This function should place the first odd number at the back of the input list. Do not return a new list - in fact this function shouldn't return anything, it should only modify the input list.

Example:

```
 >>> lst = [10, 2, 4, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 >>> push_first_odd_back(lst)
 >>> lst [10, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7]
```

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried to write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def push_odd_back (l):
    for i in range (len(l)):
        if l[i]%2!=0:
            number=l[i]
            l.pop(i)
            l.append(number)
            return l
    return l
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/pythonHW1/PushOdd.py", line 3, in push_first_odd_back
    if l[i] % 2 != 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting                                                                     (This error is occuring)

Comment: I don't know what you are using but it worked fine for me so your input might be wrong

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine now. Thankyou So much.. :)